# Access root stage instance when button is clicked

Tags: html, flash, html5-canvas, createjs

I have an instance of a button called `myBtn` on stage, and an instance of a square movie clip called `myContainer`- all of which published from flash.
Within `myContainer` i have a movieclip instance named `mySquare` which is animated via classic tween from one point of the stage to another.
When the stage is loaded i use `this.myBtn.on("click", startBtnOnClick)` to add an event listener to the button, and the function `startBtnOnClick(evt)` is indeed successfully called.
What i'm trying to achieve is to tell `myContainer` to start playing when the button is clicked, and to do so i currently need to use:
`evt.target.parent.parent.myContainer.gotoAndPlay(0)` which works, but doesn't seem to be a best practice here.
What would be a more suitable approach?

The code is generated when i publish from Adobe Flash using HTML5 document type. My addition was the `startBtnOnClick()` function definition and assigning the event handler to the `myBtn` instance

### Edit:

Two files are created when i publish. In order to play the movie you open the html file.
SquareTrial.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SquareTrial</title>

<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="SquareTrial.js"></script>

<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    exportRoot = new lib.SquareTrial();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

and SquareTrial.js:

```
(function (lib, img, cjs, ss) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes

// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 550,
    height: 400,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    manifest: []
};


// functions:

function startBtnOnClick(evt)
{
    console.log("startBtnOnClick called.");

    console.log("stage:");
    console.log(stage);

    console.log("stage.myContainer:");
    console.log(stage.myContainer);

    console.log("this.myContainer:");
    console.log(this.myContainer);
}


// symbols:


(lib.MySquare = function() {
    this.initialize();

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f().s("#000000").ss(1,1,1).p("AoWoWIQtAAIAAQtIwtAAg");
    this.shape.setTransform(53.5,53.5);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#6633FF").s().p("AoWIXIAAwtIQtAAIAAQtg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(53.5,53.5);

    this.addChild(this.shape_1,this.shape);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Container();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-1,-1,109,109);


(lib.MyBtn = function() {
    this.initialize();

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f().s("#000000").ss(1,1,1).p("AprjWITXAAIAAGtIzXAAg");
    this.shape.setTransform(62,21.5);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#0099FF").s().p("AprDXIAAmtITXAAIAAGtg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(62,21.5);

    this.addChild(this.shape_1,this.shape);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Container();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-1,-1,126,45);


(lib.MyContainer = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.mySquare = new lib.MySquare();
    this.mySquare.setTransform(53.5,53.5,1,1,0,0,0,53.5,53.5);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.mySquare).to({x:397.5},47).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-0.5,-0.5,108,108);


// stage content:
(lib.SquareTrial = function() {
    this.initialize();

    // button
    this.myContainer = new lib.MyContainer();
    this.myContainer.setTransform(102.5,99.5,1,1,0,0,0,53.5,53.5);

    this.myBtn = new lib.MyBtn();
    this.myBtn.setTransform(111,337.5,1,1,0,0,0,62,21.5);

    //this.myBtn.on("click", startBtnOnClick); //<< does not work
    this.myBtn.on("click", startBtnOnClick, this);


    this.addChild(this.myBtn,this.myContainer);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Container();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(323.5,245.5,125,314);

})(lib = lib||{}, images = images||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{});
var lib, images, createjs, ss;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for the stage, you can use the `stage` property (getter) on any display object, which returns the stage the instance lives on. It will return null if it can not reach the stage.

```
var stage = evt.target.stage;
```

Otherwise, you might want to look at your application architecture. For instance, you can bind your event handler to the current scope by passing `this` as the 3rd parameter of the `on()` method. This will make your `startBtnOnClick` method fire in your app scope, rather than making you look up the scope relative to the clicked button.

```
this.myBtn.on("click", startBtnOnClick, this);
```

---

**[Edited based on posted content]**

Your update shows that `myContainer` is a child of your Flash stage, which is actually exported as the `SquareTrial` function in your library JS (named after your FLA). This class is instantiated as `exportRoot` in the HTML.

The way you define the function inside the library is a little unorthodox. It is basically an anonymous function, but the bigger issue is that if you re-export your library from Flash, it will get overwritten. I recommend either moving it to another script you include, or actually including it in your frame script.

Anyways, on to the actual function. Since you use the `on()` method to call it in scope, the `this` variable will refer to the `SquareTrial` instance (aka the `exportRoot`). You should be able to reference `this.myContainer` in your `startBtnOnClick` method.

*The `stage` getter I suggested is not ideal, since the EaselJS stage only contains the `exportRoot`. It would also need to be accessed as `this.stage`. The `stage` reference you use **does** exist, but it is the global variable created in the index.html.*

So, using the new approach, you should be able to do this:

```
// In your frame script:
this.myBtn.on("click", startBtnOnClick, this); 

// In your function callback
console.log(this); // Should be the instance, and NOT window.
this.myContainer.gotoAndPlay(0);
```

If you decided to stick with an un-scoped, anonymous function, then you can reference your content via the global `exportRoot` variable:

```
exportRoot.myContainer.gotoAndPlay(0);
```

Hope that clears up any confusion.

Comment: On the first approach, stage is not shown as null, but stage.myContainer is "undefined". The 2nd approach works - this.myContainer is recognized and this.myContainer.gotoAndPlay(0) works. Now, i'm just at the initial steps of building my app, so i wonder if that's a proper approach.

Comment: It sounds like `this` is not equal to the stage. How are you building your content?

Comment: I edited the post so it now includes the generated code from Adobe Flash and my additions. Does it make sense?

Comment: First of all, thank you for the clear and very good answer. Second, what would be the orthodox approach? From what i understand, what you're actually saying is that SquareTrial.js parallels to Flash's library, correct?

Comment: Editing the generated file is the unorthodox approach. As I mentioned it will get overwritten when you re-export.